ZXing.NET namespace not available on .NET IOS projects
we are in process of upgrading our Xamarin.iOS app to .NET7. We need to read barcodes using camera for which we are using ZXing.Mobile nuget on our .NET 7 IOS app.
I need to add the following line to initialize the environment ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
However, ZXing.Net namespace does not appear. On calling the scanner.Scan() method, I get the error
System.NotSupportedException: MobileBarcodeScanner is unsupported on this platform.
Not sure what am i missing here. Is this nuget compatible with net8-ios?
On calling the scanner.Scan() method, i was expecting the camera to appear but it did not.

For Maui project, you should install ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls which supports .NET 8.
To initialize the plugin, just add .UseBarcodeReader()in your MauiProgram.cs, see below:
// Add the using to the top
using ZXing.Net.Maui;
using ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;


public static MauiApp Create()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseBarcodeReader(); // Make sure to add this line

    ...
}


For iOS go to your info.plist file (under the Platforms\iOS folder) and add the following permissions inside of the dict node:
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses barcode scanning to...</string>

Make sure that you enter a clear and valid reason for your app to access the camera. This description will be shown to the user.
You can refer to the github repo for more details.
